# Removing EXIF Does not work when using Different Encoders to Choose Format

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, exif, system.drawing

Im using the following code to fix the orientation of image taking into account the EXIF Orientation Tag

```
 static void FixImageOrientation(Image srce)
        {
            const int ExifOrientationId = 0x112;
            // Read orientation tag
            if (!srce.PropertyIdList.Contains(ExifOrientationId)) return;
            var prop = srce.GetPropertyItem(ExifOrientationId);
            var orient = BitConverter.ToInt16(prop.Value, 0);
            // Force value to 1
            prop.Value = BitConverter.GetBytes((short)1);
            srce.SetPropertyItem(prop);

            // Rotate/flip image according to <orient>
            switch (orient)
            {
                case 1:
                 srce.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone);
                 break;

                case 2:
                    srce.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX);
                    break;

                case 3:
                     srce.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
                     break;

                case 4:
                    srce.RotateFlip( RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX);
                    break;

                case 5:
                     srce.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipX);
                     break;

                case 6:
                    srce.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                    break;

                case 7:
                    srce.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipX);
                    break;

                case 8:
                     srce.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
                     break;

                default:
                    srce.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

This code removes the EXIF Orientation Tag properly.
And saving the image works is i simply use **`img.save`**

But the app provides user the ability to select the format of the image.For that i use the following code

```
 private void saveJpeg(string path, Bitmap img, long quality)
        {


            EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, quality);


            ImageCodecInfo Codec = this.getEncoderInfo(imgformat);

            if (Codec == null)
                return;

            EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
            encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;

            img.Save(path + ext, Codec, encoderParams);
        }
        public string getimgext(string ccodec)
        {
            if (ccodec.Equals("image/png"))
            {
                return ".png";
            }
            else if (ccodec.Equals("image/jpeg"))
            {
                return ".jpg";
            }
            else if (ccodec.Equals("image/tiff"))
            {
                return ".tif";
            }
            else if (ccodec.Equals("image/bmp"))
            {
                return ".bmp";
            }

            else if (ccodec.Equals("image/gif"))
            {
                return ".gif";
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }

        }
        private ImageCodecInfo getEncoderInfo(string mimeType)
        {
            // Get image codecs for all image formats
            ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();

            // Find the correct image codec
            for (int i = 0; i < codecs.Length; i++)
                if (codecs[i].MimeType == mimeType)
                    return codecs[i];
            return null;
        }
```

When i save the image with `SaveJpeg` the image gets saved with wrong orientation.What im i doing wrong? Please help.

***UPDATE:***

I have modified the method so that i dont need to create a new instance of the bitmap as the loop processes many files.But this does not work unless i create a new instance of the bitmap.This process consumes an additional of 10+ seconds of the processing time when compared to the old version.
Im using the code like this

```
image = (Bitmap)FixImageOrientation(Bitmap.FromFile(path));


Image FixImageOrientation(Image srce)
        {
            const int ExifOrientationId = 0x112;
            // Read orientation tag
            if (!srce.PropertyIdList.Contains(ExifOrientationId)) return srce;
            var prop = srce.GetPropertyItem(ExifOrientationId);
            var orient = BitConverter.ToInt16(prop.Value, 0);
            // Force value to 1
            prop.Value = BitConverter.GetBytes((short)1);
            srce.SetPropertyItem(prop);

            // Rotate/flip image according to <orient>
            switch (orient)
            {
                case 1:
                    srce.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone);
                    return srce;
                    

                case 2:
                    srce.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX);
                    return srce;

                case 3:
                    srce.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
                    return srce;

                case 4:
                    srce.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX);
                    return srce;

                case 5:
                    srce.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipX);
                    return srce;

                case 6:
                    srce.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                    return srce;

                case 7:
                    srce.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipX);
                    return srce;

                case 8:
                    srce.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
                    return srce;

                default:
                    srce.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone);
                    return srce;
            }
        }
```

Comment: `saveJpeg` has some compile errors, is there some code missing?

Comment: I also found some time back that if a user orients an image themselves before uploading, sometimes the results are still the wrong orientation. That was due to certain imaging programs (Microsoft Office Picture Viewer) not removing/updating the EXIF tag after reorientation. Something to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one method you have argument of type `Image` but in other `Bitmap`. So I'm **guessing** that you convert source JPEG image to Bitmap before call `FixImageOrientation`.

This will work:

```
 var jpeg = Image.FromFile("original.jpg");
 FixImageOrientation(jpeg);
 var bitmap = new Bitmap(jpeg);
 saveJpeg("new",bitmap,1);
```

This won't:

```
var jpeg = Image.FromFile("original.jpg");
var bitmap = new Bitmap(jpeg);
FixImageOrientation(bitmap);
saveJpeg("new", bitmap, 1);
```

Comment: Will try and get back.Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot :) that was indeed the issue.I had tried modifying the FixImageOrientation code to return a Bitmap.It did not work.Could you please modify the method,so that i can prevent the creation of a new object,thus saving memory.

Comment: You're welcome @techno. Can you post that modified code that didn't work? To my knowledge you can't convert an image to bitmap without creating `Bitmap` instance. So to save memory make sure that source image is disposed after bitmap creation.

Comment: im really really busy.. i will accept this answer.. please give me some time.